# writing to a text file in php

Tags: php

i have a php file A.php.Every time my page A.php is called i want it to write some data to a file.
I want to appent to a existing file and not overwrite

how do i do this

Comment: Not bothering answering, since my effort won't be honored here. 40 Questions and not a single one accepted! Impressive ...

Comment: Probably shouldn't expect an answer but I'll ask anyway - Are you sure this is really what you want to do? Unless this is a very low-traffic site, if you want to log something it would probably be "better" to write it to a database, system log, etc.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest is to use the [`file_put_contents`](http://docs.php.net/file_put_contents) function with the `FILE_APPEND` flag:

```
file_put_contents('filename', 'data', FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted, so +1.

Answer (score 3):

To write to file b.txt (for example) use this:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('b.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fclose($fp);
```

That will write "1" to b.txt every time you run it.

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php) should get you going

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "String 1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "String 2\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```