# Generate text file using php

Tags: php, html

I want to generate text file using php and save some text into it.

Comment: I agree, you could have given more background on what you want to achieve. And I want a house, too. And ponies! (Damnit, I didn't want to edit somebody elses comment, sorry about that).

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing to a text file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451590/writing-to-a-text-file-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a few ways of doing this, perhaps the easiest being [file_put_contents](http://uk.php.net/file_put_contents). For example:

```
if(file_put_contents('/path/filename.txt', 'Data to put in the file.') !== false) {
    // Data was saved to file.
    ...
}
else {
    // Data could not be saved - handle appropriately.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) or [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)&[fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).
file_put_contents default rewrite file and requires PHP5. fopen working on PHP4 and you can use optinons for opening file.
**Examples:**

file_put_contents:

```
file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

fopen&fwrite:

```
$f = fopen($file,'w'); 
fwrite($f,$content,strlen($content)); 
fclose($f);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. file_put_contents can be used to append data to a file given the correct flags.