# PHP Add string to text file

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [writing to a text file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451590/writing-to-a-text-file-in-php)

Say I wanted to add the string $ip to the text file ip.txt in the same directory. I am currently using `file_get_contents` to read from the text file.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php
  $ip = "foo";
  file_put_contents("ip.txt", $ip, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

`FILE_APPEND` will *append* the text. Absence of this flag will cause file-overwriting.

Comment: What must the permissions be on the file in order to write to it from a website?

Answer (score 9):

[`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with `FILE_APPEND` flag appends text to given file:

```
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $stringToAppend, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 5):

[`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to put contents into a file.

```
if(!file_put_contents("path/to/file.txt", $ip, FILE_APPEND)){
    // failure
}
```

Comment: Old answer but this needs flagging: `Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.`