# php save array as new column in file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Is there a way to save the contents of an array as a new column in an existing file?

My array `$total_sum`:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 2318
  [1] => 392
  [2] => 753
  [3] => 555
)
```

Add to existing `file.tsv`:

```
id   type   sum
152  new    2318
998  new    392
556  old    753
281  new    555
```

I tried:

```
foreach($total_sum as $val) {
  fwrite('/var/file.tsv', $val);
}
```

But it keeps giving me an error about type stream.  Just want to check if this is possible in php?  How would you add the column title 'sum' as well if it's not included in the array? < confused >  Would appreciate any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Add string to text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335885/php-add-string-to-text-file)

Comment: You call `fopen()` to get a stream from a filename, and you pass that as the first argument to `fwrite()`. You don't put the filename there directly.

Comment: http://us1.php.net/fputcsv

Comment: Your loop, if it worked, would replace the first two columns with the third column, not append it to each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first read the old contents of the file, so you can append the new column to each line.

```
$filename = '/var/file.tsv';
$orig = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach ($orig as $i => $line) {
    fwrite($fp, "$line\t{$total_sum[$i]}\n";
}
```

If the file has a heading line like you showed in your example, you should put the `sum` heading in `$total_sum` to keep them in sync, or splice it out of `$orig` and handle that line specially.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) file first?

```
$f = fopen('/var/file.tsv', 'a');

foreach($total_sum as $val) {
    fwrite($f, $val);
}

fclose($f);
```