# Send variable value to .txt file through .php

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, numbers

I have a script with a variable, this variable I am passing to a .php script and then from the .php script to a .txt file which then stores the number value from the variable, only problem is that when I pass the variable to the .txt file, instead of passing the number of the variable it just passes the name of it.

**Here are my scripts:**

php:

```
    <?php 

    $variableToPass= $_POST['variableToPass']; 

    $filename = "textFilePass.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $content .= $variableToPass. PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);


?>
```

html:

```
<form id="payment-form" action="chargeCard.php" method="POST" name="payment-form">
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
<input type="hidden" id="variableToPass" name="variableToPass" value="variableToPass"/> 
<input type="image"  src="butImg.png" id="Button" value="but" alt="but"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var variableToPass= 1;

document.getElementById("variableToPass").innerHTML = variableToPass;
document.getElementByID("variableToPass").value = variableToPass;

</script>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335885/php-add-string-to-text-file

Comment: The value of the input is `variableToPass` and the error in the javascript never changes that, so that's what sent to the PHP script, not `1`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById *"id is a case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the element being sought."* - So is `getElementById`. `getElementById` and `getElementByID` are two different animals altogether.

Comment: So basically I can't get the value of the variable by doing it this way?

Comment: Try removing `value="variableToPass"` from your input.

Comment: ^ that seemed to have worked for you ^ *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: Yes that worked and I have accepted the answer, but again thank you very much for all the help from all of you.

Comment: @DevLiv What is the `<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />` used for?

Comment: It is for another value sent to the .php script, but I have fixed the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"It is because I want to save the variable to be able to show it to all users on the website, so to do this I have the default value which is 1 and then I have a text input, which only allows numbers which are the variable+1 so lets say the default is 1, then I will put 2 into the input and then the .php file will get this input of 2 and save it into the .txt file, where after that the variable in the javascript will get this variable in the .txt file, and turn the new value into the variable. A bit complicated but basically it is just to save the variable for all users and not locally."*

Ok, I have pretty good idea as to what you want to do here.

***Important sidenote:*** Please go over my answer very carefully and in its entirety; I may not have fully grasped what you want to achieve here, so there are two options in my answer.

Here's what you need to do:

First check to see if the input is numeric by using `is_numeric()`.

Then assign variables and add the POST amount with the `$_POST['variableToPass']` array.

**PHP**

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['amount']) && is_numeric($_POST['amount']) ){

    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

}

else{
echo "It is not numeric. Please click back and enter an integer.";
exit;
}

$variableToPass1 = $_POST['variableToPass'];

$variableToPass = $variableToPass1 + $amount;

    $filename = "textFilePass.txt"; // make sure this file exists before executing
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $content .= $variableToPass. PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

**HTML form**

```
<form id="payment-form" action="chargeCard.php" method="POST" name="payment-form">
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
<input type="hidden" id="variableToPass" name="variableToPass" value="variableToPass"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var variableToPass= 1;

document.getElementById("variableToPass").innerHTML = variableToPass;
document.getElementById("variableToPass").value = variableToPass;

</script>
```

However, using this method will keep adding/appending to the file. If this isn't the desired result, you will need to remove the dot in:

```
$content .= $variableToPass. PHP_EOL;
         ^
```

to read as:

```
$content = $variableToPass. PHP_EOL;
```

Plus, as already stated; this line:

```
document.getElementByID("variableToPass").value = variableToPass;
```

should read as:

```
document.getElementById("variableToPass").value = variableToPass;
```

- getElementById is case-sensitive.

---

**Option 2** Using the number from the "amount" input to write to file.

This will write whatever number from the input and write it to file, and not appending to it.

If a number is not inserted and by clicking the submit button only, will write the number you've defined in `var variableToPass= 1;`

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['amount']) && is_numeric($_POST['amount']) ){

    $variableToPass  = $_POST['amount'];

}

else{

    $variableToPass = $_POST['variableToPass'];

}

    $filename = "textFilePass.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);

    $content = $variableToPass. PHP_EOL;

    file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

---

**Footnotes:**

- If you have any questions about this, or that I may not have fully understood; let me know.

Comment: I have figured out a way of fixing the problem, but thank you very much for the answer, it helped me on the way.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo here:

```
document.getElementByID("variableToPass").value = variableToPass;
                      ^
```

change it to:

```
document.getElementById("variableToPass").value = variableToPass;
```

The value doesn't get changed and stays with the default value, being `variableToPass`, which coincides with the PHP variable name.

Besides you don't need to change innerHTML - it is input, it has its value.

Comment: Answer and comments both being totally ignored by OP, *tsk tsk*.

Comment: They aren't being ignored I am just testing them out and afterwords leaving a response.

Comment: I have fixed the typo and the last "get" line for the html value is to display the variable just ignore that. But is there a way to do like I have done, but get the value number instead of the variable name?

Comment: yes, all that is aimed at getting this number. You can put 1 in value as a default, but it will be overwrite immediately by javascript anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$var_str = var_export($text, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('filename.php', $var);
```

Comment: he don't want to put that value on php script he asking about .txt file and why did you write `<?php\n\n\$$text = $var_str;\n\n?> ` script to file ? ;) 
:p

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" id="variableToPass" name="variableToPass" value="variableToPass"/>
```

This will always send the value (value="variableToPass") try changing it to (value="1") this should return 1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, only problem is that this variable value will change over time so it can't just be set to 1, it has to be the variable which is send or the amount inside the variable at the given time.

Comment: Where do you get the value from?

Comment: It is because I want to save the variable to be able to show it to all users on the website, so to do this I have the default value which is 1 and then I have a text input, which only allows numbers which are the variable+1 so lets say the default is 1, then I will put 2 into the input and then the .php file will get this input of 2 and save it into the .txt file, where after that the variable in the javascript will get this variable in the .txt file, and turn the new value into the variable. A bit complicated but basically it is just to save the variable for all users and not locally.

Comment: Oke you need to change getElementByID("variableToPass") to getElementById("variableToPass") like mentioned above and set the value to empty like this <input type="hidden" id="variableToPass" name="variableToPass" value=""/>

Comment: You will always get the value inside var variableToPass= 1; Keep in mind that you've hardcoded the variable.

Comment: I have just tested the script again, there is something wrong because it still doesn't work, I thought it worked before because there was a 1 by mistake.